# UV mapping problem

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

So I'm making this Lego figure for college and I'm having trouble with the UV mapping. It looks fine in textured view but in rendered view it displays wrong.

This link contains an images of the textured and rendered parts so you can see the difference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Eq8.jpg

Might be an easy fix but I'm just plain stupid when it comes to blender.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: agreed,your answer is in gandalf3's link

Comment: Agreed, setting the Mapping to UV should do it.